# Avada (Wordpress theme) compiled CSS: where does it compiled from?

Tags: css, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

We've recently migrated our Wordpress e-commerce site (woocommerce) to Avada from an old/buggy custom theme.
We got everything (pages and products) rebuilt in the Fusion Builder pretty easily, and tweaking with custom CSS is pretty straight forward.

But there are a few loose threads and one has me COMPLETELY stumped.

There is a WooCommerce element that is getting styled somewhere.
`.product .entry-summary div .price{}`
I cannot override it (tried `!important`), and I can't seem to find where the rule is ***originally*** written.

That being said, when I inspect it with the browser tools, the prevailing rule is found in
"`.../wp-content/uploads/avada-styles/avada-1069.css`".
When I open that CSS, there is an entire block at the top of the doc that says:
"`/********* Compiled - Do not edit *********/`"

There are a slew of "Avada-###.css" files in that directory.
They all seem to have some of those compiled rules.

Where is that compiled from?
Where can I find the source file to edit it correctly?!

## NOTE:

I have twice attempted to contact the theme-fusion support (author of the Avada theme), and haven't received a single response.
It's been several weeks, so now I'm desperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/avada-1069.css` file *is* the source.

`/*** Compiled - Do not edit ***/` is letting you know that tho file is part of the theme's core. Changes to it may be overwritten when Avast updates and there's a possibility of breaking functionality.

If you need to make changes that aren't supported by the theme's Custom CSS field, create a basic [child-theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes). The boilerplate functions.php and styles.css code are sufficient:

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

and

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Avast Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/avast-child/
 Description:  My First Child Theme :)
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     avast
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         whatever, blah
 Text Domain:  avast-child
*/

.product .entry-summary div .price{ ... }
```

Statements in the child-theme CSS sheet will overwrite those in the parent. When the theme updates, your child remains unchanged and continues doing it's job.

Before doing that, you may benefit from looking over the [Specifics on CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/%22Specifics%20on%20CSS%20Specificity%22). It breaks down the overwrite hierarchy. You could also post the code for your rule and the source rule for folks to peek at.

Comment: Turns out that, after all, my problem was chaching ...thought we had addressed that, but forgot they had added a CDN layer :j  -- Thank you @mikerose for your response. You perfectly answered the question I asked, so I marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The functions.php that AVADA provides in their child theme seems to be broken! I just swapped out the one that shipped with Avada child theme this generic boilerplate one and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the theme is dynamically generating stylesheets so editing directly won't be an option (because they will be changing anyway).

I'm not sure what all the dynamic stylesheet is loading but the WordPress way would be to first **use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)** and then:

1. Add overriding styles to your child theme's `style.css` and/or,
2. De-register the parent theme's stylesheet entirely from your child theme's `functions.php` file and use your own styles in the child themes `style.css`:

(Where `avada-dynamic-css` is the handle registered by the theme)

```
function yourname_unhook_parent_style() {
  wp_dequeue_style( 'avada-dynamic-css' );
  wp_deregister_style( 'avada-dynamic-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yourname_unhook_parent_style', 20 );
```

Comment: Yes. a) those are dynamically generated. Editing directly is not an option. b) We are using a child theme.  -  
Thanks for the `functions.php` insight ...I'll look into that